# Comparision of chef-client installation approaches

Tags: chef-infra

We planned to use Chef for our infrastructure maintenance. While going through Chef documentation and discussing with my colleagues, I got 2 approaches for installing chef-client and connecting with chef-server.

Approach-1:

Chef-client will be bootstrapped to install from chef-server. We will update list of roles/cookbooks in run-list at chef-server and control the cookbooks that are required to run at various chef-clients.

Approach-2:

Chef-client will be installed individually in the node. Then, to connect to chef-server, we will copy validation.pem(Will be deleted after first-time connectivity) from server and connect to chef-server. On register, server sends client.pem key, which will be used for further communication.

A cron-job at chef-client will take care of what cookbooks it required and accordingly download cookbooks from chef-server.

http://www.emilsoman.com/blog/2012/11/06/setting-up-chef-client/

Any one did analysis on this before and can you please provide your opinions on Scalability & Security in these 2 approaches?

Comment: Chef can be executed in server-client or solo mode.  It depends on your use case which approach is suitable.

Comment: I want to go for server-client model itself. Both approaches are of server-client model only. I am looking for comparing 2 approaches in terms of security, scalability etc.

Comment: I can't tell the difference between the two. We do not recommend using the validation key anymore, see `knife bootstrap` for the current bootstrap model. As for service vs. cron job, that's up to you, mostly doesn't matter anymore.